# How to divide values within a single column and store the result in another column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called "alerts" that looks like this.

```
user_id event   alert_type
1       imp       s
2       imp       b
3       imp       b
3       clk       b
6       imp       b
9       imp       s
9       clk       s
2       clk       b
6       clk       b
17      imp       p
18      imp       p
19      imp       s
11      imp       b
14      imp       s
1       clk       s
11      clk       b
15      imp       p
15      clk       p
20      imp       b
21      imp       b
22      imp       p
23      imp       s
24      imp       s
23      clk       s
18      clk       p
29      imp       b
29      clk       b
16      imp       p
16      clk       p
27      imp       s
28      imp       s
```

I am trying to create a new column called result for every alert_type where `result = clk/imp`

My desired output is

```
alert_type  result
b           0.7143
p           0.6
s           0.375
```

I am trying to do it this way but I know it is very inefficient.

```
select 
((select alert_type,count(*) from alerts where alert_type = 'b' and event = 'clk') / 
 (select alert_type,count(*) from alerts where alert_type = 'b' and event = 'imp')) result 
 from dual;
```

Please help me with a concise way of achieving the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
SELECT 
alert_type,
(SUM(`event` = 'clk' ) / SUM(`event` = 'imp')) AS result
FROM alerts
WHERE alert_type ='b'
GROUP BY alert_type
```

**Note:**

Since `MySQL` boolean expression resolves into `0/1` so that you can capitalize this in your use case.

`SUM(a=b) returns 1 only if a is equal to b`

**More:** Since I've used `SUM` instead of `COUNT` so you don't need be worried about `DIVIDE BY ZERO` error.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like charm. I was just curious why the event column in 3rd line is given in quotes? I am trying to learn mysql so your inputs will definitely help.

Comment: event column is not quoted rather it's enclosed by backtick (although not needed here) . If you accidentally name an identifier's name by any of the reserved words of mysql then it will generate error. To bypass this you need to ecnlose the identifier's name by backtick. But in this case you can leave the backticks for `event` column.  [**Learn when to use single quote,double quote and backtick**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks) @Sharath